# An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot start the XY application

Tags: android, automation, appium, appium-android, katalon-studio

I'm new with Katalon Studio and mobile automation. I'm trying to automate a flow in Android, installation and other setup were done, and also could created the first test scriprt (with recording function). I'm using a real mobile device (not an emulator) and it connected to Katalon successfully. But when I try to execute the test case, I'm receving the following error message:

```
ROOT CAUSE =====================
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot start the 'si.app.qa' application. Consider checking the driver's troubleshooting documentation. Original error: '*' or 'si.app.qa' never started. Consider checking the driver's troubleshooting documentation. 

For trouble shooting, please visit: https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/troubleshooting.html
================================================

03-12-2024 10:19:07 de. Test Cases/Create new goal

Elapsed time: 51,827s

Test Cases/Create new goal FAILED.
Reason:
com.kms.katalon.core.exception.StepFailedException: Unable to start app at: 'C:\Users\xxx.yyy\Katalon Studio\testAndroid\androidapp\si.app.qa-43.apk'*
```

It seems an issue related to a webdriver or environment variable but I'm not sure and cannot find any good solution for it.

```
Environment:
Katalon 9.3.1.
Node.js 20.11.1.
Appium 2.5.1.
Java 21.0.2.
```